# How to Selectively Turn Chapter Page Numbers Off in the Table of Contents

Tags: table-of-contents, chapters, page-numbering, tocloft

MWE:

```
\documentclass{book}
\usepackage{tocloft}

\begin{document}
\tableofcontents

\newpage

\cftpagenumbersoff{chapter}

\addcontentsline{toc}{chapter}{CHAPTER 1}

\cftpagenumberson{chapter}

\addcontentsline{toc}{chapter}{CHAPTER 2}

Text.
\end{document}
```

which produces the TOC:

[image]

I thought, perhaps, that using `\cftpagenumbersoff{chapter}` before the Chapter 1 entry would turn the associated page number off; and then placing `\cftpagenumberson{chapter}` before the Chapter 2 entry would turn it back on. But that doesn't seem to be working.

How may I selectively turn page numbers off for chapters in the TOC?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can add a line to the ToC with an empty page number using `\contentsline`.

[image: a]

```
\documentclass{book}

\begin{document}
    \tableofcontents    
    \newpage
    
    
    \chapter*{CHAPTER 1}        
    \addcontentsline{toc}{chapter}{CHAPTER 1}   
    
    \chapter*{CHAPTER 2}        
    \addtocontents{toc}{\protect\contentsline{chapter}{CHAPTER 2}{}{}\par}  % changed <<<<<<<<<<<
    
    \chapter*{CHAPTER 3}        
    \addcontentsline{toc}{chapter}{CHAPTER 3}
    
\end{document}
```

Comment: Thank you for this answer, it seems to work very nicely; however, when I incorporate your answer into my actual document, a dotfill appears. Do you have any idea what might be causing this?

Comment: Something in your document is modifying `\l@chapter`.  The default for book class does **not** use `\@dottedtocline`.

Comment: @jean-marie Please update your question including the complete preamble you are using.

Comment: @JohnKormylo Thank you for your comment, I'll have to spend a little more time trying to figure out what is wrong.

Comment: Thank you for your helpful answer. The preamble is long and complicated. I must spend a little more time on figuring out what the problem may be.