# How to Selectively Eliminate the Dotfill in a TOC Chapter Entry

Tags: table-of-contents, tocloft, dotfill

This question is an extension of the one posed in [How to Selectively Turn Chapter Page Numbers Off in the Table of Contents](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/668310/how-to-selectively-turn-chapter-page-numbers-off-in-the-table-of-contents)

I am using dotfill for chapter entries in the TOC; however, I would like to be able to selectively turn it off; for example, in this MWE:

```
\documentclass{book}
\usepackage{tocloft}
\renewcommand{\cftchapleader}{\dotfill}
\begin{document}
    \tableofcontents    
    \newpage
  
    \chapter*{CHAPTER 1}        
    \addcontentsline{toc}{chapter}{CHAPTER 1}   
    
    \renewcommand{\cftchapleader}{}
    
    \chapter*{CHAPTER 2}        
    \addtocontents{toc}{\protect\contentsline{chapter}{CHAPTER 2}{}{}\par} 
    
    \renewcommand{\cftchapleader}{\dotfill}
    
    \chapter*{CHAPTER 3}        
    \addcontentsline{toc}{chapter}{CHAPTER 3}
\end{document}
```

I would like to eliminate the dotfill for the Chapter 2 entry only.

However, the above code does not do this; the TOC output being:

[image]

How may I modify the above code to eliminate *both* the page number *and* the dotfill for the Chapter 2 entry only?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this code.

[image: b]

```
\documentclass{book}
\usepackage{tocloft}
\renewcommand{\cftchapleader}{\dotfill}
    
%************************************* added <<<<   
\setlength{\cftbeforesubparaskip}{1.0em plus 1pt} 
\renewcommand{\cftsubparafont}{\bfseries} 
\setlength{\cftsubparaindent}{0em}
\renewcommand{\cftsubparadotsep}{\cftnodots}
\setcounter{tocdepth}{5}
%*************************************  

\begin{document}
    \tableofcontents    
    \newpage

    \chapter*{CHAPTER 1}        
    \addcontentsline{toc}{chapter}{CHAPTER 1}   
    
    
    \chapter*{CHAPTER 2}        
    \addtocontents{toc}{\protect\contentsline{subparagraph}{CHAPTER 2}{}{}} % changed  use subparagraph instead of chapter
        
    \chapter*{CHAPTER 3}        
    \addcontentsline{toc}{chapter}{CHAPTER 3}

\end{document}
```

The line added to the ToC uses `subparagraph`  (hardly used in a book) instead of `chapter` to supress the dots.  It requires to set the font size and space above of the chapter entries.

OPTION

If you don use `\part` in your document it is possible to use

```
%************************************* added <<<<       
\setlength{\cftbeforepartskip}{1.0em plus 1pt} % added <<<<<<
\renewcommand{\cftpartfont}{\bfseries} % added <<<<<<   
%*************************************
```

and

```
\addtocontents{toc}{\protect\contentsline{part}{CHAPTER 2}{}{}} %   use part instead of chapter
```

Comment: Thank you kindly for this helpful answer.

Comment: I must have a strange actual document; when I run your edited answer as is---it seems to work fine. However, when I incorporate it into my actual document---I have problems. Perhaps I did not comment everything out from the first answer and, perhaps, a conflict results. I am now running my document with your original answer, customized a little bit---and it gives me what I am looking for except for some extra vertical space---which I'm sure I can take care of. By itself, your first answer seems to work perfectly. Any problems, I'm sure, are the result of conflicts caused on my end.

Comment: @jean-marie A vertical space  before CHAPTER 2?

Comment: Yes; not a problem with your code I'm sure, because your answer gives desired spacing. The problem must be with some kind of a conflict on my end. Without knowing the reason why, I've taken care of it by adding some negative vertical space to the TOC after the entry.